# Async/await in a signalR hub

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, signalr

I'm trying to understand the impact of using async/await in a signalR hub. Am I correct to assume that the methods `GetAllStocks` and `GetAllStocksAsync` are identical as far as a single client is concerned, and that the only difference lies in scalability? Would invoking either of these be a an awaitable operation for a client?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;

namespace StockTickR.Hubs
{
    public class StockTickerHub : Hub
    {
        private readonly StockTicker _stockTicker;

        public StockTickerHub(StockTicker stockTicker)
        {
            _stockTicker = stockTicker;
        }

        public IEnumerable<Stock> GetAllStocks()
        {
            var result = _stockTicker.GetAllStocks();
 
            return DoSomethingWithResult(result);
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<Stock>> GetAllStocksAsync()
        {
            var result = await _stockTicker.GetAllStocksAsync();

            return DoSomethingWithResult(result);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: The posted code is not correct. If you use await you need an async keyword. But if you are not doing anything after the await you should just return the task as is.

Comment: Sorry about that. I updated it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Am I correct to assume that the methods GetAllStocks and GetAllStocksAsync are identical as far as a single client is concerned, and that the only difference lies in scalability?

Yes. Similar to ASP.NET WebApi, the response is not sent until the task completes.

> Would invoking either of these be a an awaitable operation for a client?

Yes. Since there is a network (I/O) between the client and server, they can be implemented synchronously or asynchronously, and either implementation can be called synchronously or asynchronously.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I appreciate you taking the time. Funny that you of all people answered this question, because this question partly came from reading one of your blog post `Task.Run Etiquette Examples`. First you implement a WEB API Controller that does not use async, then you say "But the desktop app required a change in the service. It’s now async", and then you add the async await keywords. But why does the desktop app require the API to be async? Can't it await it anyway?

Comment: @Q-bertsuit: Only task-likes can be awaited. The code from that blog post was synchronous and didn't return a task-like, so it couldn't be awaited.

Comment: Ok, I'm a bit confused now. I thought it didn't matter if a Controller returned a Task or not since it's always awaitable? In the example you change the MandlebrotController method `ActionResult Index()` to `async Task<ActionResult> IndexAsync()`. Sorry, I'm just trying to wrap my head around how this works

Comment: @Q-bertsuit: In those examples, the desktop app isn't calling the web app; rather, both the desktop app and web app are calling into the same library.

Comment: I see! Thanks for clarifying